# I can't set the default version of Scala for Play

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt, playframework-2.2

I can't set the version of Scala for a Play application:

```
//project/Build.scala

import sbt._
import play.Project._
import sbt.Keys._

object AppBuild extends Build {
  val appName = .....
  val appVersion = .....
  val appDependencies = Seq(jdbc, anorm)

  val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies)
  lazy val buildSettings = Seq(
    organization := "fdsfds"
    ,version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT123"
    ,scalaVersion := "2.10.3"
  )
}
```

I seemed like it didn't work. Then I commented out `version` and `scalaVersion` and created a new file:

```
//project/build.sbt

version in ThisBuild := "0.1"

scalaVersion in ThisBuild := "2.10.3"
```

And yet when I say `play` is responds:

```
play 2.2.1 built with Scala 2.10.2 (running Java 1.7.0_25), http://www.playframework.com
[my_app] $ show scala-version
[info] 2.10.2
```

I'm using `sbt 0.13` and play `2.2.1`. The default (and the only I guess) scala version on my computer is `2.10.3`.

How do I make this app use scala `2.10.3` by default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default Play is using Scala used by [sbt launcher](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.1/docs/Detailed-Topics/Launcher.html), which is configured in `$PLAY_HOME/framework/sbt/play.boot.properties`.

You should be able to modify the version of Scala, Play is using by (for example) adding it to your `build.sbt`. Be sure to add it after a line `play.Project.playScalaSettings`, which defines default settings for Play. So if you add `scalaVersion := "2.10.3"` at the end of your `build.sbt` it should work.

For example, when you create a new play application your `build.sbt` should look more or less like this

```
name := "Example"

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  jdbc,
  anorm,
  cache
)     

play.Project.playScalaSettings

scalaVersion := "2.10.3"
```

Now if you run application (or console for that matter), you'll see it's using the correct version

```
Welcome to Scala version 2.10.3 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_45).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.
```

also `show scala-version` should return proper version

```
[Example] $ show scala-version
[info] 2.10.3
```

Comment: 1) `Be sure to add it after a line play.Project.playScalaSettings, which defines default settings for Play.` - how? 2) why does Play say Scala 2.10.2 is being used?

Comment: `at the end of your build.sbt it should work.` - it is already in the end, `play.Project.playScalaSettings` - are you sure it is a valid code for build.sbt?

Comment: When you create new application (for example by calling `play new`) you should have a file `build.sbt`. By default indeed `play.Project.playScalaSettings`, so you should add the new line AFTER the `play.Project.playScalaSettings` (just remember that all entries in the build.sbt must be separated with a new line). To answer second part of your comment, Play is using SBT launcher, and it's using Scala version defined in `$PLAY_HOME/framework/sbt/play.boot.properties`

Comment: There was no such a file - `Then I commented out version and scalaVersion and created a new file`. How do I do the same in Build.scala? What's the equivalent for `play.Project.playScalaSettings` from build.sbt in Build.scala?

Comment: There is only one line build.sbt, this is scalaVersion := "2.10.3". The other settings in Build.scala. And yet the default version is 2.10.2. I even changed it in $PLAY_HOME/framework/sbt/play.boot.properties to be 2.10.3, but no result.

Comment: You can also configure it in `Build.scala` like this `val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies, settings = Seq(scalaVersion := "2.10.3"))`

Comment: Sorry, have you read my question? It's all been told in it. I did that and failed.

Comment: You're right. It turned out `lazy val buildSettings = Seq(organization := "123dsf", version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT123", scalaVersion := "2.10.3")
` doesn't work for some reason. I wonder, why?